# want to connect to dynamoDB, get AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_to_region'

Tags: python, module, connect, amazon-dynamodb, attributeerror

Here is my simple code:

```
import boto.dynamodb
conn = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region(
   'us-east-1',
   aws_access_key_id='....',
   aws_secret_access_key='....')
print conn
```

and I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "startMarch28.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_to_region'
```

Comment: Which `boto` version are you using? (`boto.__version__`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `connect_to_region()` function in `boto.dynamodb` in `boto==2.2.2` version.

Upgrade the module to the latest (`2.27.0`) version:

```
pip install boto --upgrade
```

Comment: I tried that and got a Trraceback list and OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/share/pyshared/boto-2.2.2.egg-info'

Comment: @user3473556 in case it's your system python - run the command with `sudo`.